# Interaction between Activity and Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-actionbar

In my application the main activity hosts two fragments and attached to acticity as ActionBarTabs. using the following code. **NOTE: activity and the 2 fragments are defined in seperate xml layout files** (See the picture at the bottom)

```
    private void createActionTabs() {
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        //Status Tab
        String strStatus = getResources().getString(R.string.lblStatus);
        ActionBar.Tab statusTab = actionBar.newTab();

        statusTab.setText(strStatus);
        TabListener<SFrag> sFTabListener = new TabListener<SFrag>(this, strStatus, SFrag.class);
        statusTab.setTabListener(sFTabListener);
        actionBar.addTab(statusTab);

        //Controller Tab attached the same way
        .....

}
```

The ActionBar Items (start and refresh) are added using

```
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
       MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
       inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
       return true;
}
```

Now coming to my problem:

1. I want to update the data shown on the Status Fragment at application load, fragment resume and click of refresh menu item from the action bar. Now when I try to access the Status fragment from Main Activity using the following code

   ```
   SFrag frag = (SFrag) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.st_frag);

       Log.d(TAG, "In Activity SFrag is " + (frag == null ? "null" : "not null"));

       if (frag != null) {
           //calls the method to update data
           fragment.updateStatusData(statusInformation);
       }
   ```

The **getFragmentManager().findFragmentById** methods always returns null. I even tried the onResume method of the activity, the fragment objects is still returned as null. So how do I access the fragment and thus accessa  method of that fragment from host acticty.

2. Secondly, I am trying to use the action_service (its shown as Start button just for this mockup) in action bar as a toggle for satrting or stopping a background service. I can easily update the title/icon for start menu item from **onOptionsItemSelected** method (I save the current status running/stoppede in shared-preferences). but when I try to accees the menuItem at onStart/onResume of the activity by using

   ```
    MenuItem mi = (MenuItem) findViewById (R.id.action_service);
   ```

it always returns null. So How Can I access action_service menu Item in  onResume/onStart to update it.

My Application looks like this[image: My application's mockup]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all if you want to declare `MenuItem`, you should do it in this way :

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_activity, menu);
    MenuItem mRefresh = menu.findItem(R.id.refresh_menu_item);   
    return true;
}
```

About updating your `Fragment` on applications load or `Activity`'s start, just set selected the tab which holds your `Fragment` and put the code which will load the data in your `Fragment` on it's `onStart()` or `onActivityCreated()` method. You can override `onOptionsItemSelected()` in your `Fragment`, so you can update your views not from your `Activity` which holds your `Fragment`, but from it's own class.

**Edit:** Here is an example how you should handle menu from your `Fragment` :

```
    public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
            setHasOptionsMenu(true); // Do not forget this!!!
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
             super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
               inflater.inflate(R.menu.first_fragment, menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_refresh:
                // Do You stuff here   
                break;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Using this you can add and use `MenuItem`'s in your `Fragment`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I put my refresh functionality in [StatusFragment] and called it fron onStart method and it works fine. But since onCreateOptionsMenu is called on the Main Activity so the onOptionsItemSelected() doesn't get fired for the Fragment. Hence I can't invoke the refresh method even though I am capture the refresh action-bar item click on the Main Activity... Can you suggest aything for this?

Answer (score 1):

I can answer the MenuItem part just not the other part.

for the menu item as per the docs `You can safely hold on to menu (and any items created from it), making modifications to it as desired, until the next time onCreateOptionsMenu() is called.`

for example

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    actionMenu = menu;
    return true;
}
```

so basically anytime you want to change one of the items you can do this

```
MenuItem item = actionMenu.getItem(0);
```